# Как правильно сделать select из mysql на python?

Tags: mysql, python

Собственно вот есть простой код:

```
import  mysql.connector

sql = "select count(mtl_filename) cnt from mtl_file where mtl_filename=%s"

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user="developer", password="*******",
                          host="127.0.0.1",
                          database="rfi")

cursor = cnx.cursor()

mtl = 'unit'

cursor.execute(sql, (mtl))
for fn in cursor:
    cnt_files = fn
    print("found: ", cnt_files)

cnx.close()
```

Все время падаю с ошибкой: 
*mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s' at line 1*

При этом аналогичный код с *insert* отрабатывает на ура

PS
 В sql-тулзе этот select отрабатывает на ура

```
select count(mtl_filename) from mtl_file where mtl_filename='unit'
```

PPS
 Если добавить еще один параметр в запрос и в сам кортеж то все чудесно начинает работать

Comment: @Twiss не помогло

Comment: А что такое ‘cnt’ перед from в коде?

Comment: @defrag просто алиас поля в таблице. Ради интереса убрал его. Результат тот же

Comment: А что если %s в кавычки одинарные взять - ‘%s’

Comment: @defrag тогда он возвращает ноль, хотя должен вернуть 1. При этом если захардкодить в кавычках unit то возвращает правильно 1

Answer (score 1):

```
cursor.execute(sql, (mtl,))
```

запятая нужна чтобы тупл получился, а не просто одно значение в скобках.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем вся засада оказалась как запихнуть кортеж в execute.
Если ставить запятую после переменной с параметром то получал ошибку о том что число ожидаемых параметров не совпадает с числом реально переданных.
Решением стал вот такой код, где я в sql запрос добавил еще одно условие которое не влияло на логику программы:

```
import  mysql.connector

sql = "select count(mtl_filename) from mtl_file where mtl_filename = %s and idmtl_file > %s"

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user="developer", password="*******",
                          host="127.0.0.1",
                          database="rfi")

cursor = cnx.cursor()

mtl = ('unit', 0)

cursor.execute(sql, mtl)
for fn in cursor:
    cnt_files = fn
    print("found: ", cnt_files[0])

cnx.close()
```